# og:image issues finds the image but returning Unknown Error

Tags: facebook-opengraph, meta

I'm having issues with fb og:image

It reads the image but throws an

> Unknown Error

response.

I've changed it around and tried everything I possibly can.

url: www.trendiiin.com/

Answer (score 0):

The og:image URL: http://assets.trendiiin.com/microsoft-quantum-computer.gif

> Error 403. Forbidden.

...it is not accessible in public. Make sure it is.

Side Note: You should put metatags right after the opening head tag, not after a lot of CSS files.

Comment: Did you mean to say the place the fb:... meta tags **before** the CSS links? That's where I would suggest to put them rather than after the `</head>` since those should be in the `<head>` tag anyway.